# Sanitising a POST array for INSERT query

Tags: php

Morning SO,

I have a checkbox array (name = "cat[]") in a form which at present, contains six values, 1- 6 (it may contain more in the future). A user can select any number of these.

These values are then collected in:

```
$_SESSION['cat'] = $_POST['cat'];
```

(They're in a session because there's a step or two before the actual insert query)

What i want to do is Sanitise them. I have tried

```
$_SESSION['cat'] = (int)$_POST['cat'];
```

But that seems to strip all values from it.

Can someone help with the appropriate method of sanitising this for safe insertion into a database?

Thanks in advance, as always,
Dan

Comment: What are the value like? Are they all numbers? How do you to 'sanitise' them? From what you are asking, it looks like you are casting an array (`cat[]`) to an integer, which will not result in an array of integers, it will just result in an integer. You would need to loop through it, or user something like array_walk()...

Comment: Hi Dave, the array does contain (upto) six values, 1, 2, 3 etc etc. These relate to the unique id in a toxi solution for tags in my database. This works great at the moment, but sanitising it (or trying to) has stopped it working. In my Insert query i do loop through them all.

Comment: (reference): Also have a lookt at: [php filter functions](http://www.php.net/manual/ref.filter.php) especially [filter_input_array](http://www.php.net/manual/efunction.filter-input-array.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution

```
$values = array_map('intval',$_POST['cat']);
```

But that will result in all non-integer values replaced by 0, rather than removing it.

Much better solution is using [prepared statments](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) (I'm tired to tell it in each post about mysql insert... :) ), like this:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("*your query with params replaced with ?*");
foreach ($_POST['cat'] as $cat){
    //check that $cat is integer.
    if ($cat === 0 || (!empty(intval($cat)))
        $stmt->execute(array($cat));
}
```

This way you'll have double protection: you check for int yorself and `PDO` properly uses it in sql statement.

Comment: Haha, everyone is telling me to use PDO but i keep shying away because im just getting my head around this! I think i'm going to dive in and give yours a go John, thanks :)

Comment: Hehe, just to sabotage your decision: [new mysql engine supports prepared statements and object-oriented style too](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

Answer (score 0):

If with safe you mean all as integer:

```
foreach ($_POST['cat'] as $key => $value) {
   $_SESSION['cat'][] = int()$value;
}
```

Else, you could replace the `int()$value` with `mysql_real_escape_string($value)`.

**Fixed typo**

Comment: I tried real_escape_string Devator but that just seemed to strip out all the values as well (numbers 1-6). They should all be integers. I just want to ensure they're safe for insertion.

Comment: They all become empty because you are sanitizing the array as a whole. That's why I'm using a foreach loop to sanitize them one by one.

You should also use `mysql_real_escape_string` instead of int then.

Comment: That code will result in *any* variable in post casted to int and appended to $_SESSION['cat']

Comment: int is not a function, should be (int)$value or intval($value) but not int($value)

Comment: Well, almost there, except this results in the values being inserted twice! Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

What Kind of values does `$_POST['cat']` have? I'm assuming you *want* it to be an integer, but if it's not, it will spit out zero when casted to an `int`.

Make sure your `value=""` in your HTML actually contains integers. I can't say much more without the checkbox HTML.

Comment: Sorry JW, the values posted from each checkbox are '1', '2', '3' etc etc. I just want to make sure they're 'safe' (ive used escape-string on my other post entries).

Comment: It's curious that you're not getting anything from casting to an int. To answer your question, yes, casting to an int is perfectly safe; any other stuff (characters and the like) will be filtered out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mysql_real_escape_string` to make sure the string doesn't generator SQL errors and then the php `intval` function to make sure to get an integer value from the string.

Answer (score 0):

PHP:

```
if ($_POST['submit']) {
    foreach ($_POST['cat'] as $key => $value) {
        $_SESSION['cat'][] = intval(mysql_real_escape_string($value));
    }
}

if (isset($_SESSION['cat'])) {
    foreach($_SESSION['cat'] as $cat) {
        echo "Cat: $cat<br />";
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    1 <input name="cat[]" type="checkbox" value="1" /><br />
    2 <input name="cat[]" type="checkbox" value="2" /><br />
    3 <input name="cat[]" type="checkbox" value="3" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Hi Mat, this also works but its is returning the values twice for some reason. i.e. if i select 1, 3 and 5, its returning 1,3,5,1,3,5

Comment: I am not sure why that would happen, is it possible to see the HTML and PHP code you are using? Do you alter the $_SESSION variable anywhere else?

Comment: Hi Mat, well the above is going on a 'preview' page, on the actual insert page i have: foreach ($cat as $item) {$sql = "query"; $result=mysql_query($sql);} I can't see that i'm altering it at all